# About inequalities that involve the sum of divisors, the Euler's totient and the aliquot part $\sigma(n)-n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, divisors-multiples

In this post, for integers $n\geq 1$, I denote the sum of divisors $\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ as $\sigma(n)$ and the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(n)$. It's easy to check* that if we assume that $n=N$ is an odd perfect number then the inequalities

$$\frac{\sigma\left(\frac{\sigma(n)}{2}n^2\right) }{\frac{\sigma(n)}{2}(\sigma(n)-n)^2}\leq \frac{n}{\varphi(\sigma(n)-n)}\tag{1}$$

and

$$8\frac{\sigma\left(\frac{\sigma(n)}{2}n^2\right) }{\frac{\sigma(n)}{2}(\sigma(\sigma(n))-\sigma(n))^2}\leq \frac{n}{\varphi(\sigma(\sigma(n))-\sigma(n))},\tag{2}$$
hold. And it is obvious that every odd perfect number $n=N$ **is an odd integer** satisfying

$$2\mid \sigma(n).\tag{3}$$

**Example.** The odd integer $n=1102725$ is the least positive integer satisfying $(1)$ and $(3)$. But (I know that) this odd integer doesn't satisfy $(2)$.

I'm asking what work can be done for the following questions (the part A) is just a computational exercise) before I'm accepting an answer.

> **Question.** A) Please, I would like to know if you can to calculate the least odd integer $n\geq 1$ satisfying the inequality $(1)$, the condition $(3)$ and also the inequality $(2)$. B) I would like to know if it is possible to elucidate (what work can be done about this) **if the set of solutions** $n$ satisfying all requirements $n\equiv 1\text{ mod }2$, the inequalities $(1)$, $(2)$ and $2\mid \sigma(n)$) **is bounded**, that's: are there finitely/infinitely many solutions over odd integers $n\geq 1$ satisfying both inequalities together the cited condition $(3)$?  **Many thanks.**

The motivation of A) is that I'm not able (with my computer and knowledges) to calculate it.

*The calculation is easy from a well known inequality for the sum of divisors function and the Euler's totient (Exercise 9 for Chapter 3 of [1]), since for perfect numbers $\sigma(N)/2=\sigma(N)-N=N$ and thus our inequalities are simplified by using $x^a/\varphi(x^a)=x/\varphi(x)$.

**Remark:** I edit this (if can be inspiring here), to add that it is possible to state different formulae involving primorials. I hope don't bother with these aside remarks.

1. It is easy to check that if $n=N$ is an odd perfect number that satisfies $\left(n,\frac{N_l}{N_k}\right)=1$ for some integers $1\leq k<l$ with $N_t=\prod_{j=1}^t p_j$ denoting the primorial of order $t$ then the following identity holds
   $$2\frac{\varphi(N_k)}{\varphi(N_l)}\varphi\left(2n^2\frac{N_l}{N_k}\right)=\sigma(n)\varphi(n).$$
2. From this identity we claim that it is easy to check the following inequality for odd perfect numbers $n=N$ under previous assumption $\left(n,\frac{N_l}{N_k}\right)=1$
   $$\frac{\sigma\left(n^2\frac{\sigma(n)}{2}\right)}{\left(\sigma(n)-n\right)^3}\leq\frac{n\sigma(n)}{2\frac{\varphi(N_k)}{\varphi(N_l)}\varphi\left(2(\sigma(n)-n)^2\frac{N_l}{N_k}\right)}.$$

### References:

[1] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, UTM, Springer (1976).

Comment: Many thanks for your edit.

Comment: Many thanks for the attention and upvotes. If I can I'm going to post as a comment a characterization of odd perfect numbers similar than previous equations. It will be as aside comment of the post, now I'm going to offer a bounty.

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in Question A), "the condition $(3)$ and also the inequality $(3)$".

Comment: As aside comment I add a characterization for odd perfect numbers (similar than previous identitites): *An integer* $n>1$ *is an odd perfect number if and only if* $$\frac{1}{\varphi(n)}\cdot\sigma(n)=2\frac{\varphi(2n^2)}{\varphi(2n)^2}.$$

Comment: Many thanks @mathlove if you can fix it, in other case I do it in next few days, now I'm in a call center.

Comment: Alternatively, *an integer* $n>1$ *is an odd perfect number if and only if* $$\sigma(n)=2\frac{\varphi(n)}{\varphi(2n)^2}\varphi\left(2n^2\frac{N_l}{N_k}\right)\frac{\varphi(N_k)}{\varphi(N_l)}$$ 
*holds, for some choice of integers* $1\leq k<l$ with $\gcd(n,\frac{N_l}{N_k})=1$ (take $\operatorname{rad}(n)\mid N_k$).

Comment: (1/2) @mathlove I try to relate prime numbers $x>3$, imagine it as a letter L=1+\varphi(x), with $\varphi(x)$ the Euler's totient, and chirality. My thoughts are $x>1$ is a prime number if and only if $\sigma(x^2)-\sigma(x)^2=x$; also if $x,y$ are prime numbers such that $\sigma(x^2)=y$ then $\varphi(\sigma(x^2))-\varphi(x^2)=2x$ holds; finally $x=a\times b$ is a composite (non-chiral) integer with $1<a<b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then since the sum of divisors function is multiplicative we have $\sigma(a\times b)=\sigma(a)\times \sigma(b)$. Thus the equations that I was evoking

Comment: (2/2) I don't know if these (what) equations or thoughts are in the literature/OEIS are related to $\sigma(a)\sigma(b)-\sigma(ab)=0$ for composite integers, for prime numbers we have $\sigma(x)\sigma(x)-\sigma(xx)=x$, and for the mentioned special case for prime numbers satisfying $\sigma(x^2)=y$ we've $\varphi(\sigma(xx))-\varphi(xx)=2x$. Can you think about a geometrical interpretation of this (how the sum of divisors function does carry rectangles, and the reletionship to chirality)?